# Why would my HDMI output not show the same picture in "Duplicate" presentation mode? How to fix?

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, screen-capture

I have an Elgato Cam Link Pro HDMI video capture card. I expected to be able to use the "Duplicate" projector mode and record videos exactly of what I see on my screen.

However, this is not the case in at least 2 circumstances:

1. The Windows 10 22H2 logon screen does not show the blurry image in the background when entering the password. The blurry image shows on the original screen, but not in the capture card.
2. The app "2fast" does not show parts of its window in the capture card.

Example of case 1: the logon picture before entering the password is shown in Cam Link perfectly:

[image: Logon screen, not blurred]

However, when entering the password, the background simply becomes black via Cam Link, while the original laptop screen shows the blurred picture of the above golden globe in the background:

[image: Logon screen while entering the password]

Example of case 2: red regions are created by me for privacy reasons. However, the black region is the result in via Cam Link (HDMI output of the laptop), while it shows some shade of grey with some icons originally. I can't show how the app really looks like, because it doesn't allow making screenshots of itself.

[image: 2Fast via CamLink]

Main question: **how could I fix this issue so that I can record what I really see?** Bonus question because I'm curious: **what is the technical reason behind it that shows parts of the screen in black?**

Configuration: Lenovo Thinkpad 20ST-003PGE with Windows 10 22H2 x64-> HDMI output -> Elgato Cam Link Pro (Full HD, not 4K) @ HDMI port 4-> some custom PC with Ryzen 7 processor, Windows 10 22H2 x64 -> Camera capture in OBS studio 29.0.2 x64.

Comment: “what is the technical reason behind it that shows parts of the screen in black?” - Are you positive this isn’t a feature you enabled by accident to display the desktop background? Do other TOTP applications behave the same way?

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't know or have any other TOTP applications at the moment. But I could try to find some and test them.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hardware device to duplicate the HDMI output of the computer into both display devices if you need identical representation. When selecting a device, ensure it will support the bandwidth (for appropriate resolution, bith depth, and refresh rate) and features (HDCP, etc.) you need as not all devices are equally capable.

When duplicating a display output through Windows settings (or device drivers), the "duplicate" is imperfect and managed by software. Software may behave differently on each display, either purposefully (e.g. for content or user security), compatibility, or due to bugs. On a routing level, there is only one primary sync and the secondary sync may see (extremely) slightly different behavior even if the software layer outputs an identical image.